# function in bash_profile to get `ls` result, choose one of them and pass to next command

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Use case: I need to do export KEY=value_file or cat value_file frequently and there are a lot of files so that creating alias for each of them is not actionable.
Work flow:

```
XXX$: `name of the function, say ABC` SPACE
```

I will then press tab, and I want to see a list of files under certain directory. something like

```
XXX$: ABC "cursor still here"
filea fileb filec
filed filee filef
```

And finally I can complete my command

```
XXX$: ABC filee
```

I guess the function in my bash_profile would be something like, yet the following does not work.

```
ABC(){
  ls mydir
  export KEY=@$1
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with typing `.` (or `source`) space tab tab?

Comment: sorry, I dot not quite get it, what are you suggesting?

Comment: Could not understand your question... Can you please explain what are you trying to achieve - your end goal... what does ABC() do?

Comment: I want to run command ABC (which I believe is a customized function I will put in the bash_profile.) And this command will pop a list of file I choose to open or export KEY=filename. When I run ABC, and <tab>, it should auto-complete what are in a certain directory, which means I want to run it regardless `pwd`.
My operation flow is `ABC`, `TAB`, `(find and )TYPE the name of file showed`, `hit enter.`